# Windows 8 can't connect to ad-hoc network

Tags: windows-8, ad-hoc-network

I recently installed windows 8. We used to share internet via ad-hoc networks or connectify. Windows 7 was able to connect to these but windows 8 isn't. The weird thing is, when the ad-hoc connection is configured without any security (no password), then windows 8 can connect to it but not if the connection is secure. Why could that be happening?

Comment: Did you tried: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/how-to-create-wireless-ad-hoc-internet-connection-in-windows-8/

Comment: Have you tried this: http://superuser.com/questions/695658/cant-connect-ad-hoc-network-to-windows-8-1-pro