# Can't connect ad hoc network to Windows 8.1 Pro

Tags: windows-8, ad-hoc-network, netsh

I'm trying to connect to my ad hoc network through the command prompt with the the following command:

```
netsh wlan show network
```

... I get the following output:

```
SSID 3 : Range

Network Type : Adhoc
Authentication : WPA2-Personal
Encryption : CCMP
```

I am trying to connect using this:

```
netsh wlan connect Range
```

But I'm getting this error message:

```
The network specified by Profile "Range" is not available to connect
```

How can I connect to my network using `netsh wlan connect`?

Comment: `netsh wlan connect name=Range` or `netsh wlan connect ssid="SSID 3" name="Range" interface="YOUR NAME WIRELESS NETWORK CONNECTION"` test please

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem like you and finally found a solution:
The Problem is, that you need a special ad-hoc profile to connect to the network. For some weird reason you can't do that via gui anymore, but you can work direct with `netsh wlan`:

1. Create a new profile via gui (new connection in the nework center)
2. Choose "connect manual with a network"
3. Type in your network data
4. disable the check box for "start this connection automatically"
5. Now you need to change the connection type to an ad-hoc-network: open command prombt and type `netsh wlan set profileparameter name=<YOUR NETWORK NAME> ConnectionType=IBSS`
6. In command prombt you can see all networks with `netsh wlan show networks` - there should be your Ad-Hoc network which you can join now
7. To connect to your network just type `netsh wlan connect name=<YOUR NETWORK NAME>` - it will use your created profile to join the network

To disconnect later just type

```
netsh wlan disconnect
```

and your current connection will be disconnected.

(The exact names may differ from your windows version due to the fact that I just translated them on the fly from my german version)

Comment: I would like to confirm that Windows 8.1 seems to have removed GUI support for ad hoc WiFi. It's not just you. Quite a shame, I do hope they add it back